# Align items is doing the job of justify content and justify content isn't working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment, vertical-alignment

why is the align items in this code centering child elements on the x-axis instead of the y-axis and the justify content center doesn't do anything and when I remove the justify content it is still aligned on the x-axis due to align items aligning them on the x-axis:

```html
/* HTML: */

<div class="page">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="leftSide">
        <img src="./assets/images/logo.png">
      </div>
      <div class="rightSide">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What's New</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <h1>It's not just Coffee</h1>
      <h1>It's <span>Starbucks</span></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

/* CSS: */

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.rightSide {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.rightSide li{
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.rightSide li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.rightSide li a::before {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
}

.rightSide li a:hover::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.leftSide img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

I tried everything and searched but I couldn't find how to fix it. This isn't the first time it happens to me

Comment: `align-items` does not address the Y-axis. It addresses the **cross-axis**. That also means, that `justify-content` does not address the X-axis but the **main-axis**. The main axis is always equal to the flex-direction. As you use `flex-direction: column` the main-axis will be vertical (Y-axis). You can only center an element vertically if the element size is not the default `auto` (calculated to `fit-content`). To vertical center an element the container height must be higher then the contents height.

Comment: PS: Your markup is invalid. `li` can only be a child of a list (`ul`, `menu`, or `ol`)! Placing a li within a div as direct parent is invalid. In your case you should either use `ul` or `menu`. Also learnt to sue semantic tags such as using `nav` for a navbar or header for a `header` . Placing a log that is not a link itself would not be an appropriate use for `nav` but for a `header`.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 issues are not directly connected to each other.

The first issue is your misunderstanding about how Flexbox works. I highly recommend you to read the first 3 sections of ["A Complete Guide to Flexbox"](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) by Chris Coyier. Especially the section section "Background" is the part that you got wrong.

To quote Chris Coyier:

> **main axis** – The main axis of a flex container is the primary axis along which flex items are laid out. Beware, it is not necessarily horizontal; it depends on the flex-direction property (see below).

That means, that the main axis is always equal to the flex direction. That means that `justify-content` addresses the `main-axis` and `align-items` the `cross-axis`. The `justify-content` and `align-items` do not specifically address the `Y-axis` or `X-axis`!

By default the `flex-direction` is set to `row` which will align the items along the horizontal axis:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
}

.flex-item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

If you change the `flex-direction` to `column`, the main-axis will be vertical (Y-axis), and as such `justify-content` will align items along the Y-axis:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

The second issue is a pure logical issue that you don't see directly. By default the height of an element is `auto` which means that the browser will calculate the height to exactly fit the content. If you look into this snippet, you see that the element (blue border) fits perfectly the parent (red border):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; 
  border: 2px dotted red;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

logic will tell you, that to visually center an element, the element the parent element must be higher than the element itself. You can't center an element with a tightly fitting container. If you raise the height of the container to be larger then the content, you'll see that centering works correctly:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; 
  border: 2px dotted red;
  height: 80vh;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```